# I can't insert Russian letter "Б" inside the field Magicsuggest

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, magicsuggest

I can't insert russian letter "Б" inside the field Magicsuggest.
It works fine in Firefox, but the rest of the browsers don't show this letter in the field.

Comment: I've removed the code regarding this button in the file magicsuggest-min.js "KEYCODES = {COMMA: 188}". Everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead `&#1041;`

Comment: Thanks, but users of the site enter this letter on the keyboard in the search box

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the code regarding this button in the file magicsuggest-min.js "KEYCODES = {COMMA: 188}". Everything is working now.